# Node not receiving checkboxes added by javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

On the left of the page, I have the ability to add checked options to a list, all with the same `name` attribute, which then will send the whole form to the Node backend. Pretty much everything on the page is within the same form, but tags in the lower section on the left are unchecked checkboxes, while on top they are checked.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertgreenstreet/x2gfsyva/1/
(Apologies for the actual book displayed, it was chosen randomly from Google Books)

The function `addTagToList` sets the `checked` attribute for the `input` of that tag when tags are added to "Your Tags", and I can see that attribute when I inspect them.

What I'm running into is that when I get the information in `req.body.review`, it seems to only send changes changes on the right side of the page. From the left, it's only sending the tags that were loaded with the page from the database, no matter how many I add from the "Popular Tags" section or by using the search box on the left

Here's what I get in the debugger when I inspect `req.body.review`:

```js
{
  bookFinished: 'false'
  bookFinishedDate: Tue Jan 26 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
  bookStartedDate: Mon Jan 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
  starRating: '2'
  tags: (6) ['6022d922ca6aa74df87cc04b', '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc056', '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc04f', 
  '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc055', '6022d921ca6aa74df87cc046', '6022d921ca6aa74df87cc048']
    0: '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc04b'
    1: '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc056'
    2: '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc04f'
    3: '6022d922ca6aa74df87cc055'
    4: '6022d921ca6aa74df87cc046'
    5: '6022d921ca6aa74df87cc048'
    length: 6
  __proto__: Array(0)
  text: '<p>Illo porro mollitia recusandae et eveniet vitae officia. Consequatur illo qui qui tenetur 
  ex est vitae et numquam. Est excepturi totam est. Pariatur similique commodi a. Velit eligendi 
  dolor expedita id odio quibusdam deserunt. Eos dolorem sed blanditiis. asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf 
  12:55</p>'
  title: 'debitis qui quia vero vel asdf 12:55'
  __proto__: Object

}
```

I added 3 other tags, but the `tags` property is only showing the original 6 that were checked on the page when it loaded. I'd appreciate any insight on obvious things I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the CSS hiding the display of the checkbox in order to visually see what was happening to it when a tag was moving from one section to another. When moving up to 'Your Tags', the box would not be checked. But when moving out of there into either 'Search Results' or 'Popular Tags', it would become checked, even though the attributes were being explicitly set in the add/remove functions.

It looks like the 'click' event was bubbling up from the `span` elements for the "+" and "X" controls to the `label` element and firing its default handler, which is to check its associated checkbox. By the time my code interacted with it, it was basically reversing that. (I think. If anyone else knows better, let me know and I can update this)

Adding the event as an argument to the functions, and a simple `e.preventDefault();` fixed everything:

```js
function removeTagFromList(e) {
    /* Prevent checkbox from being unchecked by the click prior to being programattically unchecked, the two of which together would make it reverse */
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('removing tag');
    let parentTag = this.closest('.tag');
    if(parentTag.classList.contains('popular-tag')){
        parentTag.querySelector('input').checked = false;
        parentTag.querySelector('input').setAttribute('checked', false);
        parentTag.querySelector('.tag-count').classList.remove('not-visible');
        parentTag.querySelector('.add-tag-plus').classList.remove('not-visible');
        this.classList.add('not-visible');
        document.querySelector('.popular-tags').appendChild(parentTag);
    } else if (parentTag.classList.contains('searched-tag') && document.querySelector('#tag-search').value) {
        parentTag.querySelector('input').checked = false;
        parentTag.querySelector('.add-tag-plus').classList.remove('not-visible');
        this.classList.add('not-visible');
        document.querySelector('#tag-search-results').appendChild(parentTag);
    } else {
        parentTag.remove();
    }
};

function addTagToList(e) {
    /* Prevent checkbox from being checked by the click prior to being programattically checked, the two of which together would make it reverse */
    e.preventDefault();
    let parentTag = this.closest('.tag');
    if (parentTag !== document.querySelector('.popular-tags').querySelector('#'+parentTag.querySelector('input').getAttribute('id')).closest('.tag')) {
        parentTag.remove();
        parentTag = document.querySelector('.popular-tags').querySelector('#'+parentTag.querySelector('input').getAttribute('id')).closest('.tag');
    }
    document.querySelector('.applied-tags').appendChild(parentTag);
    parentTag.querySelector('.add-tag-plus').classList.add('not-visible');
    let tagCount = parentTag.querySelector('.tag-count');
    if (tagCount) {
        tagCount.classList.add('not-visible');
    }
    parentTag.querySelector('.remove-tag-x').classList.remove('not-visible');
    parentTag.querySelector('.tag-checkbox').checked = true;
    parentTag.querySelector('.tag-checkbox').setAttribute('checked','true');
}
```